# Did I set up my Node.js right?

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation

I'm pretty new to Node.js and just started learning the basics but already seem to be stuck from the start ('Hello World' application). Would really appreciate your help.

I installed Node.js (version 0.10.17) on my laptop (Windows7 x64), using the installer package on their [website](http://nodejs.org/download/). From there I created the *helloworld.js* file following the instructions I saw on several guides and tutorials. The file contains a single code just as shown below:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

Also I didn't know where to place the file so I just saved it on 'My Documents' folder temporarily. When I try to run the following code on the command line, to execute the javascript file I get no results.

```
node helloworld.js
```

Additionally, I've run the code that is supposed to display the application version and it also does not display anything.

Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: What output do you get if you run "node -v"?

Comment: Yes. I've also tried "$ node -v". That didn't work as well

Comment: sounds like your node is not installed, or was not installed globally. where is your node binary located?

Comment: On running 'node -v' on the command line, this is part of the error message I get: `ReferenceError: node is not defined`

Comment: @Jonathan, the 'nodejs' folder is located in my 'Program Files' folder. I'm not sure if that answers your question about the node binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `'node -v'` or `'node helloworld.js'` is meant to be typed in windows cmd prompt , not in node REPL (the green hexagon node icon )

Now , to run your examples .press Win + r , type cmd  , press enter , type node-v

To practise javascript , open that green hexagon

The reason you got the error is that the green hexagon ( Node REPL ) is a javascript realtime intrepreter and node is a variable that is undefined

Comment: Thanks a lot Rana. It runs on windows command prompt just as you said. All I had to do for the _helloworld_ command was to change the directory to where the _js_ file was located.  However I wasnt too sure of what you meant by 'praticising javascript' on the Node REPL. Did you mean writing javascript just as I would do on a web application like Dreamweaver?

Comment: yes.Its handy to test javascript quirks like these 
http://www.2ality.com/2013/04/12quirks.html

.Small guide on how to use it : http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/REPL/how-to-use-nodejs-repl